# get id from a href and include in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i need to get the id of an href, and included in a javascript, i cannot get it right.
What i want to do is in the delete_page.php get the id of the that is selected so i can update the record using it, and for that to work i need in the javascript where the delete_page.php is to show delete_page.php?id=(), thats what i need to do, if someone has an easier way to do it will be great!

THis is my code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "delete_page.php?id=",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });                
        }
    });


});

 <a href="#" class="delete" id="post-<?php echo $pid; ?>" name="delete_id">Erase page</a>
```

i need the id from the href inside the script after the delete_page.php?id=" HERE,    any   answers will be great THANKS

i also tryed
Delete

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('a.delete').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/post-/, ''),
            parent = $(this).parent();

        $.post("delete_page.php", {
            "id": id
          })
            .done(function (data) {
            parent.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    }
});
});
```

but after the message, the rest of the script is not working, the delete_page.php and the fade..
heres the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dqn61zgv/

What i want to do is in the delete_page.php get the id of the  that is selected so i can update the record using it, and for that to work i need in the javascript where the delete_page.php is to show delete_page.php?id=(), thats what i need to do, if someone has an easier way to do it will be great!

Comment: you may have to prevent the default action of the anchor click... also share the relevant html

Comment: there is no need to have `id=` in `url: "delete_page.php?id="` so `url: "delete_page.php"` then `data: {id: id}`

Comment: What is Parent->Parent? Can we see your markup?

Comment: killing the click event is necessary as mentioned above:

$('a.delete').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

That way you code has a chance to run, otherwise the link just fires like normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have id attr in clicked `a` tag then you dont need to use

```
  var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
```

to get it, just use

```
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

I will go solving this issue like this

**HTML**

```
<a class="delete" href="#" id="post-8">Delete</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.delete').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/post-/, ''),
                parent = $(this);

            $.post("delete_page.php", {"id": id })
             .done(function (data) { //am using done callback, you can try always to see script works and fade the a tag
                parent.fadeOut('slow', function () { parent.remove(); });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if( isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']) ) {
    $id = (int) $_POST['id'];

    //Update your db table 
    .....

    //echo result after update
    echo "success";
}
```

and here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqn61zgv/)

make sure your php script `delete_page.php` is present and returning 200 OK response after process

**I have updated the code, please check now its working**

Comment: THanks for the reply, but that is not working, when you click you  get the message, but the rest is not working at all, once you accept the javascript message, the rest of the script dont work, the PHP file and the fade dont work

Comment: if you can share your html I can make it work for you, fiddle will not work since the page `delete_page.php` is not found

Comment: check now i have changed `parent = $(this).parent()` part to `parent = $(this);`

Answer (score 0):

`a.delete` refers to all instances of the anchor tag `<a>` having a class `.delete`.

Judging by your `click();` method:

`$('a.delete').click(function(){..`

You should use `$(this).attr("id")` rather than `$(this).parent().parent().attr("id");`, since the click method is already bound to the said selector.

unless your HTML states otherwise. please show us.